# How to copy a data frame to a certain position in excel by python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a data frame start from a certain cell position in excel, but seems df.to_excel always start at 'A1', so any other way can do this? such as add

```
        64           65      START DATE
0     54.37        65.37   2013-05-03 00:00:00
1     43.52        51.23   2013-06-05 00:00:00
```

from cell E3:F5 (not including header and index)

Answer (score 2):

You need parameters `startrow` and `startcol` in [`DataFrame.to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=2, startcol=4)
```

Without index and columns names:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=2, startcol=4, header=False, index=False)
```

You can also check [official docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_positioning.html).

Comment: No, from [docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_positioning.html)

Comment: eh? Not this one. It's another question.

Comment: Comment below the question or tag the OP. This won't notify him.

Comment: @MYGz - Thank you.